# Extracting certain data from JSON response using JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to extract the all "cash" values from SmallerList (into a list or an array) and compare them with each other, and later use the top value on a new request.

I have been trying to write a script in BeanShell PostProcessor and failing.
Any recommendations? Thanks

```
{
    "SomeList": {
        "SmallerList": [{
            "name": "aaa",
            "sample": "Hrazerggsl2",
            "NO": "156576321467",
            "data": "917",
            "xyzxyz": "TAKEOUT",
            "dadada": "64,04 USD",
            "cash": "64,04 USD",
            "asdasde": "0,00 USD",
            "asdasdw": "833248",
            "asdasdd": 0,
            "dsdfi": true,
            "ewqwe": false,
            "ewqewq": false,
            "irqfsais": true,
            "gggggg": false,
            "asdasda": false,
            "gffffv": false
        }, {
            "name": "aaa",
            "sample": "Hrazerggsl2",
            "NO": "156576321467",
            "data": "917",
            "xyzxyz": "TAKEOUT",
            "dadada": "94,04 USD",
            "cash": "154,04 USD",
            "asdasde": "0,00 USD",
            "asdasdw": "833248",
            "asdasdd": 0,
            "dsdfi": true,
            "ewqwe": false,
            "ewqewq": false,
            "irqfsais": true,
            "gggggg": false,
            "asdasda": false,
            "gffffv": false
        }, {
            "name": "aaa",
            "sample": "Hrazerggsl2",
            "NO": "156576321467",
            "data": "917",
            "xyzxyz": "TAKEOUT",
            "dadada": "64,04 USD",
            "cash": "624,04 USD",
            "asdasde": "0,00 USD",
            "asdasdw": "833248",
            "asdasdd": 0,
            "dsdfi": true,
            "ewqwe": false,
            "ewqewq": false,
            "irqfsais": true,
            "gggggg": false,
            "asdasda": false,
            "gffffv": false
        }],
        "drqwname": "aadasdaa",
            "sample": "Hdasdrazerggsl2",
            "NO": "156576321467",
            "data": "917",
            "xyzxyz": "TAKEOUT",
            "dadada": "64,04 USD",
            "cash": "64,04 USD",
            "asdasde": "0,00 USD",
            "asdasdw": "833248",
            "asdasdd": 0,
            "dsdfi": true,
            "ewqwe": false,
            "ewqewq": false,
            "irqfsais": true,
            "gggggg": false,
            "asdasda": false,
            "gffffv": false
    },
    "list": {
        "payment": [{
            "name": "asdasdasdasd"
        }, {
            "name": "asdasrqweqwe"
        }, {
            "name": "asgfdsf"
        }, {
            "name": "asdfasdfa"
        }],
        "name": "dad"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. The JSON path extractor might be a good way to do this. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/

Comment: cant compare data with path extractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/). It is very easy to use.

Check  [this](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)   for the path expressions to be used. (scroll down to the section - The Differences Between XPath and JSONPath)

In your case, `$..cash` will return all the `cash` as given below. 
`allcash` is the variable i used.

```
allcash=["64,04 USD","64,04 USD","154,04 USD","624,04 USD"]
allcash_1=64,04 USD
allcash_2=64,04 USD
allcash_3=154,04 USD
allcash_4=624,04 USD
```

Comment: how can i get the index of the smallList after I do this. for example if i pick allcash_4 i need to send the index of the 4th list as a response